# Listen globally for all iron-signals

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Is there any way to intercept all the [iron-signals](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-signals) being sent *without* explicitly specifying their name in the iron-signals listener?

#### Use case

- I want to do some [Google Analytics Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) on the events that take place within my app
- Since events are being already sent in my app, i'd like to intercept those that are already being sent (and filter them appropriately to get just the ones I want)

#### Current implementation

I'm firing iron signals throughout my app to facilitate communication between my different elements like so:

```
// throughout the app
this.fire("iron-signal", {name: "do-foo"});
this.fire("iron-signal", {name: "do-bar"});
this.fire("iron-signal", {name: "do-baz"});
```

Now I want for another element, let's call it `analytics-tracker.html` to intercept all `<iron-signal>`'s being fired. This is a naive solution to this:

```
// in analytics-tracker.html
<iron-signals on-iron-signal-do-foo="trackEvent"></iron-signals>
<iron-signals on-iron-signal-do-bar="trackEvent"></iron-signals>
<iron-signals on-iron-signal-do-baz="trackEvent"></iron-signals>
```

Adding an `<iron-signals>` element for each and every event soon becomes unmanageable.

#### A possible solution

I can probably "bundle" all events as a single namespaced event which can be tracked like so:

```
// throughout the app
this.fire("iron-signal", {name: "general-event", data: { type: "Do Foo"}});
this.fire("iron-signal", {name: "general-event", data: { type: "Do Bar"}});
this.fire("iron-signal", {name: "general-event", data: { type: "Do Baz"}});

// in analytics-tracker.html
<iron-signals on-iron-signal-general-event="trackEvent"></iron-signals>
```

#### An ideal solution

E.g something like this:

```
// throughout the app
this.fire("iron-signal", {name: "do-foo"});
this.fire("iron-signal", {name: "do-bar"});
this.fire("iron-signal", {name: "do-baz"});

// in analytics-tracker.html
<iron-signals on-iron-signal-*="trackEvent"></iron-signals>
```

Is there any way to do something similar to the *ideal solution*?

Comment: i don't think `iron-signal` supports your `ideal solution`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make an event listener for this and thats the most simple solution:

```
// ...
ready: function()
{
    // signal listener at document
    document.addEventListener('iron-signal', event => {
       this.trackEvent( event.detail );
    });
}
// ...
```

The iron-signals is listening a global CustomEvent in document where the `event.detail` has a `name` and the `data` values and then the iron-signals element dispatching the name based events in the notify method.